# How do I dissolve to a predetermined number of contiguous geographies based on equal division of a value?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

Let's say I have a layer that is the state of Oklahoma, broken up by county, and I want to dissolve it into contiguous regions of roughly equal population size, and I want to define how many regions there will be.

So, if the state's population is 100, and I want 7 regions, I would get 7 different contiguous regions where the total population is [(100/7) plus or minus one standard deviation or less]

I have the state layer by county, and I have the population numbers in my table.

Is that something QGIS can do? How would I go about this?